# How can I troubleshoot a dehumidifier evaporator which frosts up quickly?

Tags: air-conditioning, dehumidifier

This dehumidifier is about two years old.  The evaporator is icing up almost immediately after turning it on.  This picture is about 20 seconds after turning it on.   After about an hour the bottom third of the evaporator is covered in ice.

The filter, evaporator and insides are very clean.  The drain is very clean and not blocked.  The fan is blowing well and air is crossing the coils.  Room temp is about 68F.

My cheapo leak detector detects no leak.

The freeze is at one end of the evaporator, near where a pipe connects it to the compressor.  The other end is not very cold and the condenser is not very warm anywhere.

I don't have the tools or skill to diagnose the sealed system, it doesn't have the ports anyway, and an A/C callout costs as much as a new machine.

So ... my guess is the refrigerant has leaked out completely and the machine is not serviceable.

**Question**:  Are there any other diagnostics or steps worth taking before giving up on this?

[image]

Comment: Is the fan blowing air across the coils?  If it is, then likely coolant has leaked out and it's not economically viable to repair.

Comment: Related to Milwrdfan's comment (but not applicable in your specific case), is that you get similar symptoms if the filter is clogged. In both cases there is too little air-flow to provide the warm air required to transfer heat to the coils.

Comment: Fan is blowing, added that to question.